# Inserting an object is causing it to be updated multiple times before it finishes

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, debug, order-of-execution

Been trying to navigate around this opportunity object that has been causing us deployment issues for a while now (aka anytime a new anything is added, high chance of older test classes to error out with soql 101 exceed).

Created some test data and put a plethora of logging and realized inserting a basic opportunity fires off before/after updates 4 times. got 6 field update workflow rules for creation, and 2 process builders.

According to salesforce documentation

> If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before
>   update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one
>   more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation
>   rules, flows, duplicate rules, processes, and escalation rules are not
>   run again.

So i'm a bit confused at what is causing the excessive updates? Been trying to scan through this 12mb file and im not sure if there is something obvious that can link why this record is being updated multiple times.

```
WF_ACTION  Field Update: 7; Flow Trigger: 10;
```

In this log what does 10 flow triggers mean? that 10 process builder/lightning processes were fired off? Don't think we have that many for opportunity.

Comment: We need to see the code Zhang. And also remember that a transaction can affect a lot of other processes. Share the code of that trigger and lets see what we can help you with.

Comment: use less verbose logging to get a handle on what is going on - perhaps only WF INFO and DB INFO

Comment: good idea with the logging verbose settings. The code... well its a bit large to dump here but nothing there I've noticed updates anything or fires off something else that would update back the opp. I'm focusing purely on insert right now so going bare minimum should 'in theory' be the cleanest way... Is there documentation for what all the WF/DB stuff means in the logs mean? Sometimes its a bit hard to follow with how things are spaced if it meant this wf met criteria or what not.

Comment: An after trigger can very easily get you into recursion (I.e fire triggers again). You should check that the objects are not re-updated in the trigger itself.